# MATLAB sum series function

Tags: matlab, function

I am very new in Matlab. I just try to implement sum of series 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!..... . But I could not find out how to do it. So far I did just sum of numbers. Help please.

```
for ii = 1:length(a)
    sum_a = sum_a + a(ii)
    sum_a



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 0 : 10; % elements of the series
x = 2;  % value of x
s = sum(x .^ n ./ factorial(n)); % sum
```

Comment: @cherry can you tell me why this gives me different result?                                                         function [output args] = my_function(a)
And also why you put .'s in .^ and ./??? Sorry if my questions are too easy
n=length(a);
x=2;
s = sum(x .^ n ./ factorial(n));
s
    







end

Comment: @user6548945 `different` with comparison to what? I do not know what your `a` is. My code calculates sum with 11 terms for one value of `x`. Or do you want to perform calculations for the vector of `x` values?

Comment: well basically you have n= 0:10. But I am just wondering how to get n from the user so that it will start from 0 till the number that user will type. Everything is going to be the same but n is coming from user....

Comment: @user6548945 so what? `n = 0 : variable_with_integer_from_user;`

Comment: thats strahge because when i had n=0:10 I had answer 6.3890. After I changed n=0: user_input.. I have 7.3890 @cheery

Comment: @user6548945 precision of the sum depends on number of terms. the more terms you have - the more precise results you will get.

Comment: Oh i got it. Why you use ./ and .^ instead of just / and ^? And thank you for helping to understand!!! @Cheery

Comment: @user6548945 These are element-wise operations (element by element) http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html because n is a vector

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your answer is:

```
n = 0:input('variable?')
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cheery's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153839/2586922) is perfectly valid when the number of terms of the series is small. For large values, a faster approach is as follows. This is more efficient because it avoids repeating multiplications:

```
m = 10;
x = 2;
result = 1+sum(cumprod(x./[1:m]));
```

Example running time for `m = 1000; x = 1;`

```
tic
for k = 1:1e4
    result = 1+sum(cumprod(x./[1:m]));
end 
toc

tic
for k = 1:1e4
    result = sum(x.^(0:m)./factorial(0:m));
end 
toc
```

gives

```
Elapsed time is 1.572464 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.999566 seconds.
```